# Image Classification approach for Text images

Tags: image-classification, ocr

Let me introduce myself as a beginner to machine learning problems.

We are trying to build a system to classify images of text-data like bills, orders, bank-statements etc. We started with the image classification approach with some-what larger data-set to train. This gave a good percentage of predictions in test.

But in real-world samples, the problem we see is that, there is no standard layouts  or strict rules in producing these text-documents. So the image classification is not giving good results any more. Classifications are going wrong because of common white backgrounds / logos is what we suspect. 
Different attempts to gray-scale the images, remove the non-text contents etc we tried, but it does not improve much.

Since arguments to shift to OCR based recognition & classification are increasing we are having a thought towards that too.

My doubt is image classification for text-images is a right approach or not?

Comment: Dropbox blog contains a nice description of a similar project https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2017/04/creating-a-modern-ocr-pipeline-using-computer-vision-and-deep-learning/

Comment: Thanks, the link describes about OCR based approach for a different motive. I just wanted to know, whether image classification can achieve similar result in classifying different document types?